# Animating NSLayoutConstraints changes (and the objects that have constraints to the changed one)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have an `UIImageView` object which is goes on and off screen at the touch of a `UIButton`, and I'm doing that by changing it's `NSLayoutConstraints`. I have successfully animated that 'movement' using the following code:

```
    self.addY.constant = 44.0f;
    [self.addingScreen setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
        [self.addingScreen layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

where addY is the constraint to the top of the screen and addingScreen is my `UIImageView`object. My problem is that I have a series of objects with vertical spacing constraints to addingScreen, and I wanted them to slide along with it. What happens tho, is that those objects instantaneously move to their final frame while the `UIImageView` slowly follows in the 0.5seconds I set in code. How do I get those objects to move along with the `UIImageView`? thanks for the help :)

Comment: Have you tried calling `layoutIfNeeded` on the closest common parent of all of the related views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you should call layoutIfNeeded also to other views that you want to move. For example try calling [self.view layoutIfNeeded] in animateWithDuration block